# chrome request pending for long time

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-devtools

When testing my web app on Chrome, I notice one request take way too long time to load (sometimes 20 seconds).

According to heroku log

```
at=info method=GET path="/1/message_feeds?competition_id=xxx" host=xxx.xxxxxxx.com request_id=0e521307-ea37-41c8-9aaa-cebec40fe106 fwd="80.216.26.9" dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=184ms status=200 bytes=11738
```

It indicates the the request is served by server for 184ms;

I also checked request timing from chrome dev tool, it shows the complete request time is less than 1 sec.

[image: timing]

*Note: the same request load in less than 1 sec in Safari and Firefox*

#### Why it took such a long time to load in Chrome?