# Why are HTTP requests getting stuck on pending in Chrome?

Tags: php, angular, apache, google-chrome

Language/Tool versions:

1. @angular/cli: 1.2.0
2. PHP 7.0.8
3. Zend Expressive 2
4. Apache 2.4.23
5. Chrome 65.0.3325.181
6. Windows 7

Issue:

I have an Angular2 application which uses a PHP application as an API for all the XHR requests. The application works fine but when the `Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly` option is enabled in Chrome, and when the application is reloaded HTTP requests sent inside `ngOnInit()` of the component gets stuck for very long. Either the request will resolve itself after 10s-2-3mins, etc or the request(s) will also resolve if I send another request(for example, a request upon a click event on the DOM)

Things I tried:

1. I went through multiple posts (such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990737/chrome-request-pending-for-long-time), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585918/what-does-pending-mean-for-request-in-chrome-developer-window), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010156/stalled-and-pending-ajax-requests-by-jquery-in-chrome/30068579), etc) with a similar problem but none were very
   useful, I read that this could happen if I have multiple numbers of HTTP requests. In my case, I tried isolating the requests and now I am sending only one request upon initialization of the component. Even one single request gets stuck. My console will show a failed `GET` request and then keeps waiting, upon resolution, there will be a successful `OPTIONS` request and then a successful `GET`.
2. I was not sure if this is a problem with my frontend Angular
   application or the backend PHP application, so upon initialization
   of the component, I called a random API endpoint:
   `http://api.randomuser.me/` rather than requesting my API endpoint.
   In this case, the request succeeds without any delay(although it
   shows CORS errors). So I think the problem resides in either my
   backend API or the Apache web server.
3. I tried to see if something is causing the delay in the API, but the application's entry point itself is not hit until the request is successful from the browser.

I would also like to share my virtual host configuration. If you find any problems there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName someName.api
DocumentRoot path_to_public_dir
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
<Directory path_to_public_dir>

    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(local\.)?(localhost:4200|someDomain.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin

    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} –d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    Options -Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Please note:

- I have also tried with setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
  header inside the application itself, but still no luck.
- The application works just fine on Mozilla or on Chrome when the
  prediction service is not enabled

Your suggestions/answers on to what all could be the possible causes for such a behavior would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you have multiple requests sent at once to your backend? Chrome can only have 6 connections to the same host

Comment: I had 5 requests sent at once, but then I tried sending only one request at once and even that was resulting in pending

Answer (score 7):

Well, I think, doing the following has removed the lag from my machine.

Before the solution, here are my assumptions:

1. Chrome is doing parallel requests whenever "Prediction service to
   load pages quickly is enabled"
2. My Apache web server was not handling those parallel requests.

Solution:

1. I included the [`mpm`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html) modules file for apache. You can find the
   below line in `httpd.conf` file:

   `#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf` and uncomment it.

   Windows uses the [mpm_winnt_module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_winnt.html) for mpm.

   > This Multi-Processing Module (MPM) is the default for the Windows NT operating systems. It uses a single control process which
   >   launches a single child process which in turn creates threads to
   >   handle requests
2. Find the lines below and uncomment them:

   ```
   EnableMMAP off        
   EnableSendfile on

   AcceptFilter http none
   AcceptFilter https none

   #Extra Notes
   #mmap is memory map by apache, don't know I have uncommented this, had read about
   this somewhere, but anyway its Off so should not be a Burden on OS
   #EnableSendFile:Delivering static files? This link may help:
   https://groups.drupal.org/node/68333
   #AcceptFilter: windows mpm module, suggests to keep it as none. 
   I went through this : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html
   and have set AcceptFilter http/https as "connect", it works fine for me. 
   Please note: I am using Apache 2.4.23
   ```
3. Restart your apache

That's it!

I am leaving this question as unaccepted because:

1. I don't know if what I did is right.
2. Although I enabled the `winnt` module, I couldn't find the module
   file anywhere in my apache directory, although changes in the
   ThreadsPerChild is reflected, I guess apache doesn't need an
   external `winnt` module.
3. Although I can observe that the page load speed has increased and
   requests are not getting stuck anymore, I can still see interleaved
   `failed and finshed` requests for every request in my chrome
   console.

Your answers will be really valuable and make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by enabling mod_deflate and configure gzip in the asset requests. Some assets, like javascript (jquery library) slowly 5s of download while others are requested with less than 30ms. I hope its help others.

See my environment made by HomeBrew:

Apache/2.4.52
PHP 7.4.28
Mysql 5.7