# Angular Post request goes to pending status and does not hit the server

Tags: java, angular, web-services

I am trying to get the user list for a email Id using a post request , Sometimes the post request goes to pending status and it stays in the same status forever.If I restart the tomcat then the request works but after some times the same issue occurs.

> Below is the post method calling in angular

```
loadBOEDetailsListByEmail(emailId, password) {
const url = `${environment.url}backofficeemployee/detailsByBoeEmailId/`;
const params = {
  resetEmail: emailId
};
const myHeader = new HttpHeaders();
myHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.http.post(url, params, { headers: myHeader }).subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      if (response && response.data && response.data[0] !== undefined) {
        this.accountList = response.data;
        const boe = response.data[0];
        this.checkAccountValidity(boe, password, observer);
      } else {
        observer.error('No account found');
      }
    },
    () => observer.error('Employee service call failed')
  );
});
```

}

> In the java side this is how I am receiving

```
    // Backoffice employee - Details by BoeUserId
@PostMapping(value = "/detailsByBoeEmailId/")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getBackofficeemployeeDetailsByBoeEmailId(@RequestBody ResetpasswordRequestDto requestDto) {
        log.info(" boeEmailId in getBackofficeemployeeDetails {}", requestDto.getResetEmail());
        try {
            List<BackofficeemployeeResponseDto> backofficeemployeeResponseDto = backofficeemployeeService
                    .getByBoeEmailId(requestDto.getResetEmail());
            return JsonUtils.mapOK(backofficeemployeeResponseDto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in getBackofficeemployeeDetailsByBoeEmailId", e);
            return JsonUtils.mapError(ERROR_MSG + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733634/why-are-http-requests-getting-stuck-on-pending-in-chrome

Comment: @xyz Do you know where to make the changes for the above mentioned link in  tomcat.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't